# There's no altair package in my anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, package, altair

When I try to import altair in Jupyternotebook, it tells me that there's no module named altair. (I'm using python 3.7). I went to anaconda environments and checked the available packages, but it didn't list altair. I tried installing the package, but it gives me this error while trying to do so:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url 
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/gcc7/win-64'

Answer (score 0):

Click Start, search, or select Anaconda Prompt from the menu

and Write this command

```
conda install -c conda-forge altair
```